# Nunit "partitioning" tests

Tags: c#-4.0, nunit

I have a number of test fixures all in the same assembly. I want to classify some of the test methods so that I can run subsets of the tests contained within each fixture. So for instance:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTests 
{
    [Test]
    [Classification="One"]
    [Classification="Two"]
    public void TestA()
    {
    }
    [Test]
    [Classification="One"]
    public void TestB()
    {
    }
    [Test]
    [Classification="Three"]
    public void TestC()
    {
    }
}
```

So in some cases I want to run all the tests. In some cases I want to run those with a particular "classification" (my made up attribute). All of this ultimately driven by TeamCity.

Is this possible in some way shape or form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [Category Attribute](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Category-Attribute).

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTests 
{
    [Test]
    [Category("One")]
    [Category("Two")]
    public void TestA()
    {
    }

    [Test]
    [Category("One")]
    public void TestB()
    {
    }

    [Test]
    [Category("Three")]
    public void TestC()
    {
    }
}
```

You can then run the groups using the `--where` option in the NUnit console runner. (Assuming NUnit v3+)

```
nunit3-console mytest.dll --where "cat == Urgent"
```